# setting tabIndex of inputs and I still can't tab at all in ie9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, tabindex

Using ruby on rails form generator to create a lot of input fields.

You can tab though the form just fine in Chrome/Firefox but in IE9 the tabbing is broken.

So I did some research and decided to set the `tabIndex` of the inputs like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
    if(isIE){
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
            inputs[i].setAttribute("tabIndex", ""+i+"");
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

Fairly quick fix, anyways, I test it out, and the `inputs` have a `tabIndex` now, but they are still not tabbing correctly. **Why is this not working? And does anyone have a better solution?**

**Edit:** The tabbing being broken refers to this behavior:

I click on the first input field hit tab, and the input loses focus, but the next input doesn't gain focus. If I hit tab again, then I just end up with my focus on the first input again. This repeats in a never ending cycle.

Also I am aware of `text-areas` and `selects` not being inputs, all I'm trying to do at this point is just get some sort of tabbing functionality working. Even if it skips these elements.

Link to site: [right here](http://staging.fliprogram.com/policies/new) open in IE9 to see faulty tab behavior.
Link to validation plugin code: [right here](http://pastie.org/5617729)

Comment: Please clarify _'not tabbing correctly'_. Keep in mind that some input elements are not of tag `input` (like `select` and `textarea`).

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I edited for clarity.

Comment: Is there anything else messing with the focus or tabIndex? Are there maybe elements with `tabIndex` set somewhere?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen no, there is nothing else setting the `tabIndex` of any elements. Their are hidden `inputs` at the top of the page, but they have a `tabIndex` as well, if you click on the first visible `input`, it has a `tabIndex` of `3` so when I hit tab it should just go to the next index right? As far as I can tell it doesn't even focus on the hidden `inputs`!

Comment: Your approach doesn't look right - instead of trying to work around it, I'd look for the bug source. Even IE6 will respect the tab order of inputs, the issue is probably some code in another JS or your ruby generator is generating glitchy markup.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Well that's what I thought, but 2 things made me try this approach, the first was that viewing the source, I can't find any missing closing tags (of course there are tons, so I may be missing one) but the second is that tabbing is 100% functional in Chrome/Firefox. I would expect broken markup to at least glitch the tab functionality somewhere in those browsers.

Comment: Yes, I also understand that your approach *should* work, but as it still doesn't, hence I assume the problem is being caused by some script. It'd be much easier to find a fix/proper workaround if the issue was reproduce-able in an isolated test case, I'm not good with RoR. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I just posted a link to the site, where you can observe the behavior.

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but you could just use: `setAttribute("tabIndex", i);` rather than concatenating the `i` variable with two empty-strings.

Comment: Oh I see. Busy day, sorry for the late replies. Will take a quick look at the link. Debugging IE is a pain as usual, but I'll add that the bug also shows in my IE10 Preview.

Comment: If I block activeX on IE, the tabbing works as expected but validation doesn't occur. Seems like it is related to your script as I first guessed.

Comment: All the JS in your page is compressed so it is nearly impossible to debug properly. There is way too many browser sniffing in it - about ~20 matches for `msie`. jQuery does use some of these to e.g. setup the `$.browser` variables, but the majority of the browser sniffing seems to come from a plugin. I'd suggest stripping out the form validation plugin and check how the tabbing goes in IE, if that doesn't solve it then try the same disabling other plugins until you find the culprit and post its code so we can review it.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Removing the validation plugin, did indeed make tabbing work again. I can post the code for the validator, but its simply the plugin that works with twitter bootstrap css for forms. So now what?

Comment: Open an issue on their [GH project](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap) I guess. `=]`

Comment: No wait, it seems to be an issue with [JQuery.tools](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools). Your code looks fine, it should be a problem with the plugin itself.

Comment: Try upgrading to the [latest version](https://raw.github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/master/src/validator/validator.js) and check if that helps. Not sure whether you can replace just the validator module, just in case you need the full library - http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try instead doing

```
inputs[i].tabIndex = i
```

instead of setAttribute, per the MS example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534654(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: the problem is not that the `tabIndex` is not being set, it is. The problem is that despite the inputs having a `tabIndex` you still can't tab though them.